# Trunk push error: "Source code for your Pod was not accessible to CocoaPods Trunk"

Tags: cocoapods

I'm having trouble pushing an update to a pod (Audiobus).

"pod trunk push" seems to successfully validate (downloads the git repository, builds, etc), but then drops out with a 403 Forbidden error when doing a POST to /api/v1/pods with the podspec content, along with the message:

"Source code for your Pod was not accessible to CocoaPods Trunk. Is it a private repo or behind a username/password on http?"

I have verified that I'm registered ("pod trunk me" shows I am logged in with correct email address, an owner of the pod).

The repository once required HTTP authentication, but after seeing the above error, I disabled auth. I've verified that there's now open access to the git repository by cloning the repository from a separate, unauthenticated machine (git clone https://developer.audiob.us/download/SDK.git test --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.2).

Is this a bug in trunk.cocoapods.org? What am I missing?

Cheers in advance,

Michael

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this? I'm getting same issue because of my pod is private.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to make your repo commit tag name the same version name you have on your package podspec file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by this also, this has been running for [a few weeks now](https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org/pull/137) and this is the first time a problem has come up. When I run the command locally I don't see a problem. I don't know if you've edited the question, but I had a reference to `https://developer.audiob.us/download/SDK.git/?url=download/SDK.git` which didn't work with the `git ls-remote`. Perhaps it doesn't redirect like git clone does?

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's strange! Where did that "...?url=download/SDK.git" URL come from? I just tried git ls-remote on the URL in the podspec (https://developer.audiob.us/download/SDK.git) and that seems to work fine.

Comment: No idea, it was in my paste buffer when I first tried the `git ls-remote` for the first time.

Comment: Ah, okay. So.. any theories as to why we can no longer push? We've launched kinda a high-profile SDK update this week, and it's been a bit embarrassing that we still haven't updated the Pod. Would really like to get this sorted.

Comment: I've just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org/pull/141) fixing it!

Comment: Great news! That's indeed fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Any one who may come upon this issue but the other answer does not help. Make sure you have the correct branch in your podspec. Having the incorrect branch will also cause this error to occur.